# Is there a way to prevent & from using a specific parent selector in Less?

Tags: css, less

I have some less code using the `&` symbol. Here is what it looks like

```
.class1 {
   .class2 {
      & > &-item {
         // Some rule
      }
   }
}
```

From looking online, it seems like this gets compiled to this in CSS

```
.class1 .class2 > .class1 .class2-item {
   // Some rule
}
```

Here's my problem: I want to only have the `&` target the `class2` and ignore the `class1`. So I'm looking for a way to compile the less to look like this

```
.class1 .class2 > .class2-item {
   // Some rule
}
```

My code is a bit more complicated. In actuality, I am importing everything starting at `class2` and wrapping it in `class1` so I can't just remove the `class1` selector. My actual code looks like this

```
.class1 {
   @import 'other-style.less';
}
```

Since the code is imported, I can't remove the `&` selector.

Is there a way to make it so `class1` doesn't get targetted with the `&` selector?

Comment: What exactly are you importing where?
As a simple solution would seem to just manually write out the selector in css style which still should be valid in less.
Is there a reason you can't do that due to the import?

Comment: My code is trying to import everything starting at class2 and wrapping it all in class1. So I can't remove the & selector because it wasn't written by me.

Comment: You can Change Selector Order https://lesscss.org/features/ by adding the & at the end of lines instead of the beginning, but it feels like here you just write your styles without class1 instead?

Comment: I can't actually change any of the code using `&`, so maybe I just need to stop using class1. That would bring other challenges, but if this solution isn't possible then you're probably right that it's better to look into other ways of handling it.